# Flutter - Execute optional function received by parameter on widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm starting out in flutter and I was trying to receive a callback in a widget but I can't resolve the null checker.

I leave an example screenshot

[Code example one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3zXm.png)

I tried to solve as the lint comments but I have no idea how to validate that it is not null

[Code example two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR66q.png)

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the

```
if(onDelete == null)
```

you can simply do this

```
onDelete?.call(houseId)
```

This will do the check and the call at the same time